# How to iterate code and save each output to a list

Tags: python

I'm just learning how to code and I've encountered a problem I can't seem to work around. I've built a strategy for a simple game of chance (similar to the Martingale strategy for those familiar) and I want to run the code n number of times and save the output of each iteration so I can aggregate the results. Note the current 'for' loop is part of my code, I tried using another 'for' loop to run the entire program n times to no avail. Thanks heaps in advance. Apologies if this is a silly question. Here is my code:

```
import math
import random
import heartrate 
heartrate.trace(browser=True)

mult = 1.2
winChance = 0.8250

balance = 259
x = 0 
for i in range (0,500):
        bet1 = balance/259
        balance = balance-bet1
        print(balance)
        n = random.random()
        if n > winChance:
            bet2 = (bet1*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
            balance = balance-bet2  

            n = random.random()
            if n > winChance:
                bet3 = ((bet1+bet2)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                balance = balance-bet3

                n = random.random()
                if n > winChance:
                    bet4 = ((bet1+bet2+bet3)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                    balance = balance-bet4

                    n = random.random()
                    if n > winChance:
                        bet5 = ((bet1+bet2+bet3+bet4)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                        balance = balance-bet5
                        print("end")
                        break

                    else: 
                        balance = balance = bet4*mult

                else:
                    balance = balance + bet3*mult


            else:
                balance = balance + bet2*mult

        else:
            balance = balance + bet1*mult
```

Comment: I would recommend taking a good basic Python tutorial. You'll probably enjoy the part about functions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question and code correctly (doubtful), this change would do what you ask for: Running your original code `N` times (with N = 10):

```
$ diff -u iterate.py.orig iterate.py
--- iterate.py.orig 2022-03-20 13:02:54.010642003 +0100
+++ iterate.py  2022-03-20 13:17:35.368615800 +0100
@@ -5,10 +5,12 @@
 
 mult = 1.2
 winChance = 0.8250
+end_balances = []
 
-balance = 259
-x = 0 
-for i in range (0,500):
+for _ in range(10):
+    balance = 259
+    x = 0 
+    for i in range (0,500):
         bet1 = balance/259
         balance = balance-bet1
         print(balance)
@@ -35,7 +37,7 @@
                         break
 
                     else: 
-                        balance = balance = bet4*mult
+                        balance = balance + bet4*mult
 
                 else:
                     balance = balance + bet3*mult
@@ -47,3 +49,6 @@
         else:
             balance = balance + bet1*mult       
 
+    end_balances.append(balance)
+
+print(end_balances)
```

Here is the full code:

```py
import math
import random
import heartrate 
heartrate.trace(browser=True)

mult = 1.2
winChance = 0.8250
end_balances = []

for _ in range(10):
    balance = 259
    x = 0 
    for i in range (0,500):
        bet1 = balance/259
        balance = balance-bet1
        print(balance)
        n = random.random()
        if n > winChance:
            bet2 = (bet1*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
            balance = balance-bet2  

            n = random.random()
            if n > winChance:
                bet3 = ((bet1+bet2)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                balance = balance-bet3

                n = random.random()
                if n > winChance:
                    bet4 = ((bet1+bet2+bet3)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                    balance = balance-bet4

                    n = random.random()
                    if n > winChance:
                        bet5 = ((bet1+bet2+bet3+bet4)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                        balance = balance-bet5
                        print("end")
                        break

                    else: 
                        balance = balance + bet4*mult

                else:
                    balance = balance + bet3*mult


            else:
                balance = balance + bet2*mult

        else:
            balance = balance + bet1*mult       

    end_balances.append(balance)

print(end_balances)
```

Note that you normally would extract the inner loop into a separate function.

*Edit*: Fixed the typo in the innermost `else` as well.

Comment: I think now I understood your comment, agreed on your solution. +1

Comment: Hey @Bluehorn, Thanks so much for your comment! I've had a crack at simplifying the code and I think I've made some really good progress. Are you aware of a way I can show you the updated code on here as it says its too long to post in a comment? I just have one quick question about using multiple loops. Again, I really appreciate your help, this is all very new to me and I feel like I've made more progress from your advice than my lectures!!! All the best.

Comment: @iHaveAQuestion maybe this question fits better on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

I am not aware how to discuss iterative code improvements on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can start by creating an empty list such as:

```
balance_end = []
```

And then appending the final balance after each iteration (I have fixed the first else which had a typo as well), such as:

```
                else: 
                    balance = balance + bet4*mult
                    balance_end.append(balance)
            else:
                balance = balance + bet3*mult
                balance_end.append(balance)

        else:
            balance = balance + bet2*mult
            balance_end.append(balance)
    else:
        balance = balance + bet1*mult       
        balance_end.append(balance)
```

Finally, you can safely assume that the `balance_end` index will match the number of iteration - 1 and the value, is the corresponding value of said iteration.

Comment: From my understanding he wants to run the same computation with different random numbers. So for each iteration of the outer loop balance must be reset.

Comment: Hmm, to my understanding balance is re-adjusted at the end of each game based on the result, while the random component (chance) is changed in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt to simplify things (to be honest, the code is quite convoluted and difficult to understand):

```
def bet(win_chance, previous_bets, mult):
    if random.random() > win_chance:
        this_bet = -1 * ((sum(previous_bets)*(1/(mult-1)))+previous_bets[0])
    else:
        this_bet = previous_bets[-1]*mult
    return this_bet

# initialise variables
mult = 1.2
win_chance = 0.8250
balance = 259

for i in range(500):
    previous_bets = []
    previous_bets.append(balance/259)
    balance -= previous_bets[0]

    for i in range(5):
        lost = bet(win_chance, previous_bets, mult)
        balance += previous_bets[-1]
        if not lost:
            break
    else:
        # lost streak after 5 attempts
        print('end')

    print(balance)
```

Answer (score -1):

create a list and append balance values to it

```
import math
import random
import heartrate 
heartrate.trace(browser=True)

mult = 1.2
winChance = 0.8250

balance = 259
x = 0 
values = list()
for i in range (0,500):
        stop = False
        bet1 = balance/259
        balance = balance-bet1
        print(balance)
        n = random.random()
        if n > winChance:
            bet2 = (bet1*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
            balance = balance-bet2  

            n = random.random()
            if n > winChance:
                bet3 = ((bet1+bet2)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                balance = balance-bet3

                n = random.random()
                if n > winChance:
                    bet4 = ((bet1+bet2+bet3)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                    balance = balance-bet4

                    n = random.random()
                    if n > winChance:
                        bet5 = ((bet1+bet2+bet3+bet4)*(1/(mult-1)))+bet1
                        balance = balance-bet5
                        print("end")
                        stop = True

                    else: 
                        balance = balance = bet4*mult

                else:
                    balance = balance + bet3*mult


            else:
                balance = balance + bet2*mult

        else:
            balance = balance + bet1*mult       
        values.append(balance)
        if stop:
            break
```

Comment: Kindly consider adjusting the error in the first else as well.